# Editar un ArrayList desde otra clase

Tags: java, arraylist

EDIT: Lo que realmente quiero es, por así decirlo, crear una ArrayList en la Clase Clientes, para así, dese la Clase "Semáforo" o "Cajas", poder llenarla/eliminar elementos. DESDE LA CLASE CLIENTES. Muchas gracias.

Tengo un programa sencillo que estoy realizando.
Tengo 3 clases, Cliente, Cajas, Semaforos.(Estoy haciendo prácticas de Semáforos, pero de momento no he tenido problema con ellos)

El caso es que quiero llenar un ArrayList con clientes en la clase Cliente, el problema es que cuando intento llenar la clase desde otra clase y acceder a esos datos, pero no se como acceder a los mismos datos desde otra clase que no es donde la llamo.

**Clase Semaforos(Main)**

```
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        int numClientes = 5;
        int numCajas = 2;
        
       
       Cajas ca = new Cajas();
       Clientes c = new Clientes();
       c.getColaClientes();
       c.populateColaClientes(numClientes);
           
       ca.array();
       for(int i = 0; i< c.getColaClientes().size(); i++){
           System.out.println(c.getColaClientes().get(i).toString());
       }

    }
    
}
```

**Clase Cliente**

```
public class Clientes {
    int iCliente;
    ArrayList<Clientes> colaClientes;
    
    public Clientes(){
        
    }
    
    public Clientes(int i){
        this.iCliente = i;
    }
    public String esperar(){
        
        return "El cliente " + iCliente + " está esperando en la fila";
    }
    
   public void populateColaClientes(int numClientes){
       Clientes c;
       for(int i = 0; i < numClientes; i++){
           c = new Clientes(i);
           this.colaClientes.add(c);
           System.out.println("El cliente " + i + " ha llegado a la cola");
       }
   }
    
    public ArrayList<Clientes> getColaClientes(){
        if(this.colaClientes == null){
            colaClientes = new ArrayList<Clientes>();
        }
    return this.colaClientes;
}
    public int getICliente(){
        return this.iCliente;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Clientes{" + "iCliente=" + iCliente + ", colaClientes=" + colaClientes + '}';
    }
    
    
    
    
}
```

**Clase Cajas**

```
public class Cajas implements Runnable {

    int numCaja;
     
    Clientes c = new Clientes();
    int clientesAtendidos;
    Semaphore cajaAbierta = new Semaphore(1);
    Semaphore aux; 
    public Cajas(){
}


    public Cajas(int i, Semaphore s){
        this.numCaja = i;
        this.aux = s;
        
    }

    public String atenderCliente() {
        this.clientesAtendidos++;
        return "Cliente atendido";
    }
    
//METODO PARA INTENTAR COMPROBAR QUE ME LLEGA ALGUN ELEMENTO DEL ARRAYLIST
    public void array(){
        for (int i = 0; i< c.getColaClientes().size(); i++){
            System.out.println(c.getColaClientes().get(i).toString() + " desde el hilo");
        }
    }
```

Cuando hago en la clase **Semaforos** getColaClientes y populateClientes, el bucle for muestra los toString de los objetos, pero cuando lo hago desde **Cajas** obtengo que el tamaño de mi lista es 0.

¿Alguna forma de solventar mi problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes un objeto de la clase `Cliente` en tu clase `Cajas` y aunque lo hayas nombre como el objeto de la clase `Cliente` en tu clase `Semaforo` **"c"** son distintos por el que esta en `Semaforo` aplica el `metodo populateColaClientes()`...Entonces puedes obtener lo valores del ArrayList requerido de la siguiente manera

1 tu método array() recibe como parámetro un ArrayList

```
 public void array(ArrayList<Clientes>lista){
        for (int i = 0; i< lista.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(lista.get(i).toString() + " desde el hilo");
        }
        }
```

2 En tu metodo Main

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        int numClientes = 5;
        int numCajas = 2;
        
       
       Cajas ca = new Cajas();
       Clientes c = new Clientes();
       c.getColaClientes();
       c.populateColaClientes(numClientes);
       
       ca.array(c.getColaClientes());

       for(int i = 0; i< c.getColaClientes().size(); i++){
           System.out.println(c.getColaClientes().get(i).toString());
       }

    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero creo que no me explique bien, lo que quiero es crear un ArrayList<Clientes> en la Clase clientes, y entonces llenarlo de clientes para así, desde la clase "Semaforos" o "Cajas", poder hacer lista.remove() o trabajar con los mismos datos, haciendo eso que dices no creo que consiguiera lo mismo.

Comment: @nWolfe3113 cambiaste la receta xD!! para poder hacer eso lo  mejor es que crees metodos que reciban como parametros un arraylist de tipo Clientes en la clase cajas o semaforo y poder modificarlas a tu antojo el punto es que si vas a crear objetos de la clase Clientes en semaforo o cajas y luego acceder al arraylist te va a pasar lo que te detalle en la respuesta

Comment: Oh, entiendo. Mi idea era utilizar algo similar a un MainViewModel en Android, pero no se si era algo que podía hacer en java. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Como bien dijo @Draumaturgo en un comentario a su respuesta, la respuesta para el EDIT está en pasar por parámetro el ArrayList, y así se solventan los problemas.
Decido ponerlo como respuesta por si la gente no lee los comentarios.